# How to tell symfony to load my custom routing.yml configuration

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-routing

I'm trying to achieve this 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html#more-advanced-loaders

I need the bundle routing to automatically activate itself when the bundle is registered

so I created this file into the path

`src/Gabriel\AdminPanelBundle\Routing\AdvancedLoader.php`

with the content

```
<?php
//namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Routing;
namespace Gabriel\AdminPanelBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class AdvancedLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();

        $resource = '@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/import_routing.yml';
        $type = 'yaml';

        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource, $type);

        $collection->addCollection($importedRoutes);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return $type === 'advanced_extra';
    }
}
```

I copied this configuration

```
gabriel_admin_panel:
    resource: "@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /superuser
```

from

```
/app/config/routing.yml
```

and pasted it into my own configuration file

```
/src/Gabriel/AdminPanelBundle/Resources/config/import_routing.yml
```

The problem:

> Symfony2 completely ignores my AdvancedLoader.php file, I can put any
>   syntax error in it and the site won't even throw an error, also the
>   router:debug doesn't show the routes that are defined inside of the
>   bundle unless I move the configuration back into its original router.yml file.

PS: clearing the cache doesn't change anything

Edit: when I add the service and the resource, this error appears

> FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException: Circular reference
>   detected in "/app/config/routing_dev.yml"
>   ("/app/config/routing_dev.yml" > "/app/config/routing.yml" > "." >
>   "@GabrielAdminPanelBundle/Controller/" >
>   "/app/config/routing_dev.yml").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could have missed some steps in the process.

First one: did you define the service?

```
services:
    gabriel.routing_loader:
        class: Gabriel\AdminPanelBundle\Routing\AdvancedLoader
        tags:
            - { name: routing.loader }
```

Note the tag. As the documentation says:

> Notice the tag routing.loader. All services with this tag will be
>   marked as potential route loaders and added as specialized routers to
>   the DelegatingLoader.

Second but very important because, as the documentation says, if you didn't add this lines your routing loader wouldn't be called:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
Gabriel_Extra:
    resource: .
    type: advanced_extra
```

The important part here is the type key. Its value should be "advanced_extra" in your case. This is the type which your `AdvancedLoader` supports and this will make sure its load() method gets called. The resource key is insignificant for the `AdvancedLoader`, so it is set to ".".

I think it will get loaded now.

Comment: no :(, now it throws an error and breaks the whole app, please check the edit on the OP (I cleared the cache too)

Comment: The problem you mentioned in the first place is solved, this is a new one. The error states it clearly: the `import_routing.yml` file you're using causes a circular reference. Do the proper changes to the `import_routing.yml` (you copied-pasted it, so no wonder it's causing the problem: one calls to the other and so on).

Comment: allright, since its a new error, I will create a new question if I don't manage to solve this, thanks for your help